# How will clr handle standard events in C# compared to c++ for windows controls?

Tags: c#, c++, events, clr

How is c# handle a event under the hood in clr, for standard win32 controls,
say a button:

Example: (c#)

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Click += (_, __) => { MessageBox.Show("You clicked me !"); };
    }
```

Is it like c++, in the main message loop?`

Example:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

switch (message)
{

case WM_COMMAND:


    if(hWnd>0 && hWnd==buttonhwnd) //Button click
    {
        callback_button();
    }

default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

I mean will all standard controls in c# send every signal, like click, mouse over,
etc. to a simular loop - and then to callback registred in the source code? Like my lambda exemple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the basic mechanism is the same.  However, Winforms (and somewhat WPF) significantly alters the message routing.  In Windows, a child control sends notifications to its parent window.  The Winforms plumbing changes that by a mixture of window sub-classing and message reflecting to have code run in the control itself.  A button's OnClick() method for example.

From where, through event subscriptions, any other class can receive the Click event callback.  A common pattern for example is not to have the panel on which you place a button process the callback but the upper level form.  This buys a great deal of flexibility over the native Windows way.

Answer (score 1):

That's the other way around.

There's a message loop, one for your application. I suspect it is somewhere around the `Application` class. The loop dispatches all incoming messages to handlers built somewhere into the `Control` class.

And then, a built in handler checks whether or not the control instance has a delegate attached to the event and if this is so, the event is called.

Comment: Well, its like that i meant :)